# Error in model prediction using hmmlearn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hmmlearn

Hi I have a dataframe test, I am trying to predict using a Gaussian HMM with hmmlearn.

When I do this:

```
y = model.predict(test) 
y
```

I get the hmm working fine producing and array of states

however if i do this:

```
for i in range(0,len(test)):
    y = model.predict(test[:i])
```

all I get is y being set to 1.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE

here is the code that does work iterating through

The training set was 0-249:

```
for i in range(251,len(X)):
    test = X[:i]
    y = model.predict(test)
    print(y[len(y)-1])
```

Comment: Are you sure about `y` being all-ones for all `i` in the forloop? This shouldn't be the case at least for the last iteration where `i` is `len(test) - 1`.

Comment: Hi, the only way I can get it to work is by appending a vector of values incrementally to the training set from the test set and running prediction on the new set. Is that by design or is it possible for the current state/transition mat etc to remain in memory post prediction within the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMM models sequences of observations. If you feed a single observation into `predict` (which does [Viterbi decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) by default) you essentially reduce the prediction to the `argmax` over

```
(model.startprob_ * model.predict_proba(test[i:i + 1])).argmax()
```

which can be dominated by `startprob_`, e.g. if `startprob = [10**-8, 1 - 10**-8]`. This could explain the all-ones behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Ha that makes sense, Does 'map' suffer from the same issue? my hack offers a work around but are there more rigorous methods to solve this? Btw its a great library you have built.

Comment: Yes, MAP prediction runs forward-backward algorithm, which reduces to the same formula for a single observation.

Could you maybe state more precisely what you are after? Is it incremental prediction?

Comment: Yes it is incremental prediction in real time. I can give you more details by mail if you prefer plus the data etc.

Comment: This is a [relevant issue](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/issues/144) over at GitHub. I suggest we continue the discussion there.